# Ошибка при получении количества событий с помощью GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents

Tags: c++, winapi

```
HANDLE csb = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
// BOOL res = SetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE, csb);   // TRUE
// BOOL res2 = SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, csb); // TRUE
SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(csb);
DWORD eventsCount;
GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(csb, &eventsCount); // ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE
```

Созданный консольный буффер корректно работает с операциями чтения\записи символов. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение подсказали на MSDN.

Ошибка заключается в том, функция `GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents` работает с дескриптором, который можно получить с помощью `GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)`. Поэтому, корректный код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
HANDLE csb = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(csb);
DWORD eventsCount;
GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &eventsCount);
```

Для отлавливания нажатий кнопок и прочих событий тоже необходимо использовать дескриптор, возвращаемый функцией `GetStdHandle`.